# Search string and replace id number with img tag using id number

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace, explode

I have a string of text:

```
$myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ||||0101|||| amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu nisl sapien. Suspendisse quam mauris, eleifend in velit eget, molestie posuere urna. Nunc a dolor semper, sollicitudin orci et, suscipit arcu. Suspendisse ||||0103|||| augue erat, accumsan nec tellus vel, hendrerit ||||0102|||| tincidunt quam. Proin sit amet nunc non dolor pretium bibendum. Nunc aliquam, turpis iaculis ornare fermentum, felis ||||0104|||| neque lobortis neque";
```

I need to search through this text and replace all instances of `||||0101||||` with `<img src="0101.jpg"/>` & `||||0102||||` with `<img src="0102.jpg"/>` etc.

I can get all the instances of ids between the pipes using the below:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
     if($i % 2) {
         $myStringPartsArray = explode("||||", $myString);
         $answer = $myStringPartsArray[$i];
         echo $answer."<br>";
     }    
}
```

but I am struggling to replace each instance with an image tag that uses the same id. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: something with `preg_replace_callback("#\|\|\|\|(\d+)\|\|\|\|#", …)`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean replace each instance that uses the same id?

Comment: Thanks. Just need to be pointed in the direction of preg_replace. ncs's answer below solves exactly what I am trying to do... replace number id between pipes in a string of text with an image of the same name!

Answer (score 2):

```
$myString = preg_replace('`\|\|\|\|(\d+)\|\|\|\|`', '<img src="$1.jpg"/>', $myString);
```